# How can I quantitatively compare the average sound intensity of two different audio clips?

Tags: acoustics, intensity

Let's say I have two different sound clips of two different people snoring. The intensity of the audio in both clips will be fluctuating throughout and peak when the person is inhaling.

Is there an efficient way of computing the average intensity of sound in each clip for a quantitative comparison, or is the best way to go about this just to manually calculate the average of each sound peak in each audio clip to do a comparison?

Comment: Unless the samples are taken with the same microphone and at the same distance from the snorer, the results are meaningless. Having the same sound card helps, but that's likely to be true. Same room shape also helps, as well as controlling for outside noise, and don't forget to check the recording settings (which also means same software)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 1):

The amount of energy in a wave is proportional to the square of the amplitude so what you need to compare is the average of the square of the amplitude.